# how to execute prepared statement in a for loop to fetch data from tables in jsp?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc, prepared-statement

what is wrong in this code? I am getting this error.

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'attendance where sub_id='3' and reg_no='1111'' at line 1
```

Code

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con =
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sms", "root", "*****");

    int k;
    String sub = "";
    int t_class[] = new int[counter];
    int att_class[] = new int[counter];
    int tallo_class[] = new int[counter];

    PreparedStatement ps3;
    PreparedStatement ps4;
    PreparedStatement ps5;

    for (k = 0; k < (counter - 1); k++) {

        sub = subjects_id[k];

        //START : getting total no of classes held 
        ps3 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FORM attendance where sub_id=? and reg_no=?");

        ps3.setString(1, sub);
        ps3.setString(2, reg_no);

        ResultSet rs3 = ps3.executeQuery();

        rs3.next();
        t_class[k] = rs3.getInt(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should that be "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM"... (not FORM)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So one big tip is you want to `prepare` your statement outside of the loop. That is kind of the point of preparing it(Also, parameterizing the inputs). You can re-use the statement, then as stated above you misspelled the word `FROM`.

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attendance where sub_id=? and reg_no=?");
        for (int i = 0; i < (k - 1); i++) {
            statement.setString(1, sub);
            statement.setString(2, reg_no);
            ResultSet rs3 = ps3.executeQuery();
            rs3.next();
            t_class[k] = rs3.getInt(1);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your SQL query. You have given FROM as FORM. It should be

```
ps3 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attendance where sub_id=? and reg_no=?");
```

Also since you are using the same `PreparedStatement` throughout the loop, then its better you keep the `PreparedStatement` outside the loop. If you have sql statment which keeps changing inside the loop, then only its worth using it in the loop. If its keep changing, then just use `Statement` instead of `PreparedStatement`, else the very purpose of `PreparedStatement` is lost as you keep changing it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `FROM` instead of `FORM`. The error message clearly indicates that the issue is after the required `FROM` keyword.

```
ps3 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attendance where sub_id=? and reg_no=?");
```

Comment: Thanks alot man... i was worried about logic and i made a simple grammer mistake